# Sendgrid not accepting username/password

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, sendgrid

I am following https://www.udemy.com/course/the-complete-ruby-on-rails-developer-course/ and while I was able to send an email on development just fine but on Heroku was another deal. Upon using devise to sign up, heroku throws a 535 error telling me I have a bad username/password. I checked my config vars and sendgrid_username and password were indeed set. I ran heroku run printenv and here's what it spit out.

```
RAILS_SERVE_STATIC_FILES=enabled
DATABASE_URL=postgres://
GEM_PATH=/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0:
PORT=18178
RAILS_ENV=production
RAILS_LOG_TO_STDOUT=enabled
COLUMNS=80
TERM=xterm-256color
RACK_ENV=production
SHLVL=1
SENDGRID_PASSWORD=SG.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
SENDGRID_USERNAME=my-api-key
MALLOC_ARENA_MAX=2
```

I also use this intializer

```
ActionMailer::Base.delivery_method = :smtp
 ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
  address:        'smtp.sendgrid.net',
  port:           '587',
  authentication: :plain,
  user_name:      ENV['SENDGRID_USERNAME'],
  password:       ENV['SENDGRID_PASSWORD'],
  domain:         'my-app.herokuapp.com',
  enable_starttls_auto: true
 }
```

I would like to use this as a stepping stone to teach myself how to set up a basic contact form, but right now I can't quite understand why the password and username aren't being set.

I've been looking at this too long and need a fresh set of eyes (and sleep). Let me know if you need any more code.

Update: I’m beginning to think there is something fishy on Sendgrid’s end. I’ll contact support later on and try to get to the bottom of this and update later as to what the issue was.

Comment: Assuming you aren't hiding the domain for privacy....I believe your domain needs to be set to your actual heroku domain (not just heroku.com). Also, what is the format of your SENDGRID_USERNAME and PASSWORD? It should be something like `app123456789@heroku.com` for the USERNAME and a alphanumeric password. In addition (not sure if this matters), but most examples have the port number as an integer, not a string.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Yes, the “heroku.com” in my initializer is actually “my-website.heroku.com”  and I will edit the OP to eliminate the confusion. As for the username and password, the instructor in the video showed us to us the name of the API Key that we generated in sendgrid for the username and the one-time-shown password that comes up after the key is created. Is that correct? I did edit the Username in heroku to my app’s name just to give it a shot but that was a no go either.

Comment: Also, for the port number, I do not have a clue how to alter that. And technically, since I did this project months ago on the same computer and it worked (though dummy here obviously forgot something) I'm not certain how that could've changed since then.

Comment: And I also changed the password to the API Key id. Still no go.

Answer (score 2):

Okay guys, part of it was a rookie mistake here and another part was that the video was made for rails 4.

First off, my mistake was that I misunderstood which value to put where. I was putting in the API Key id that is listed underneath your sendgrid name as the password. That was incorrect. Your sendgrid username is the name YOU give your key when creating it, the sendgrid password is the one time password flashed in front of you upon creation. Don't lose that.

Secondly I have to give a shout out to @TONYD at Udemy who gave this detailed answer of how to set up rails 5.2 to rails 6 apps and why. Dude, I owe you a beer for all the trouble you saved me. :)

Sendgrid credentials in Rails 5.2 - Proper way
1

Tony · Lecture 257 · a year ago
So from other tutorials I had done the .profile method to save SendGrid username and password credentials didn't seem correct anymore. (At least for local development - I'm doing this in MacOS using VS Code)  I looked around and found this article on using the encrypted credentials.yml.enc file to store these things.  It's nice as it's encrypted, its specific to the project, and your setup for future versions of Rails.

https://www.viget.com/articles/storing-secret-credentials-in-rails-5-2-and-up/

One important note in it is the --wait command depending on the editor your using! :)

The article doesn't say exactly how to format the credentials for sendgrid, but I found this gem with a description of how to setup the format:

https://github.com/padovanl/progettoRuby

```
 sendgrid:
  user_name: <sendgrid_user_name>
  password: <sendgrid_pwd>
```

Just loose the < >

The user_name will be:  apikey

The password is the apikey generated earlier in the tutorial.

So inside the credentials.yml.enc file it should end up looking something like this:

```
  sendgrid:
   user_name: apikey
   password: 145534yourapikey-etc-etc
```

Next - you will need to configure the actionmailer seperatly for the development environment and production environment...

So don't put the ActionMailer block in environement.rb.

Instead in development.rb put this block:

```
 ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
   :address => 'smtp.sendgrid.net',
   :port => '587',
   :authentication => :plain,
   :user_name => Rails.application.credentials[:sendgrid][:user_name],
   :password => Rails.application.credentials[:sendgrid][:password],
   :domain => 'heroku.com',
   :enable_starttls_auto => true
 }
  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :test
  config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 'localhost:3000' }
```

**note**    :host line - put in your url per the video - I'm doing this locally so for me it localhost:3000

Then in production.rb put this block:

```
config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
  :user_name => ENV['SENDGRID_USERNAME'],
  :password => ENV['SENDGRID_PASSWORD'],
  :domain => 'yourdomain.com',
  :address => 'smtp.sendgrid.net',
  :port => 587,
  :authentication => :plain,
  :enable_starttls_auto => true
 }
  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
  config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 'photo-app-tonyd.herokuapp.com', :protocol => 'https' }
```